# Python, combine unique contents in 3 columns (Excel spreadsheet)

Tags: python, excel, list

Good day.There’re some data in an Excel spreadsheet, structuring like this:

[image]

It’s wanted to put the unique values in the 3 columns together, nicely into a format like:

```
Mike to America for Hotel; Meal
```

and

```
Kate to Europe; America for Transport
```

etc

I can only work out for 2 columns.

```
the_file = xlrd.open_workbook("testing.xlsx")
the_sheet = the_file.sheet_by_name("Sheet1")

products = defaultdict(list)

for row_index in range(1, the_sheet.nrows):
    products[str(the_sheet.cell(row_index, 0).value)].append(the_sheet.cell(row_index, 1).value) 

for product, v in products.items()
    print product + " to " + ";".join(set(v))
```

the output is:

```
Mike to America
Hulk to America;Asia
Kate to Europe;America
Dave to Europe
Jack to Europe;America;Asia
Luci to Asia
```

What’s the way to make the lines work for 3 columns together?
Thank you.

Comment: I don't see where you're adding the cell(row_index, 2) into the pipe.

Comment: @steppo, because I don't know how and where to add them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think there's a more pythonic way to do it but this is what I came up with:

```
from collections import defaultdict


l = [
    ['mike', 'america', 'hotel'],
    ['mike', 'america', 'meal'],
    ['jack', 'america', 'meal'],
    ['jack', 'europe', 'hotel'],
    ['jack', 'america', 'bonus'],
    ['jack', 'asia', 'hotel'],
    ['dave', 'europe', 'meal'],
]

people = defaultdict(list)
people_places = defaultdict(list)

for row_index in range(len(l)):
    people[l[row_index][0]].append(l[row_index][1])
    people_places[l[row_index][0] + '|' + l[row_index][1]].append(l[row_index][2])

for p, k in people.items():
    activity = []
    for place in k:
        activity += people_places[p + '|' + place]
    print '{} to {} for {}'.format(
        p,
        ';'.join(set(k)),
        ';'.join(set(activity))
    )
```

You can translate the code to use directly spreadsheet rows and cells or extract the list `l` first with something like:

```
l = []
with xlrd.open_workbook("testing.xlsx") as the_file:
    the_sheet = the_file.sheet_by_name("Sheet1")

    for row_index in range(1, the_sheet.nrows):
        l.append([
            the_sheet.cell(row_index, 0).value, 
            the_sheet.cell(row_index, 1).value, 
            the_sheet.cell(row_index, 2).value])
```

Comment: thank you. could you pelase add on the way to make the big list l as well?

Comment: Added some hint on list extraction. If you're into datasets extraction you could eventually look at _pandas_ (http://pandas.pydata.org) as a great tool for automating this kind of tasks.

Answer (score 1):

First you extract the rows you want here I make it as a nested list i.e.
`[[col1, col2, col3],[col1, col2, col3]]`

```
box = list()
bigbox = []
for i in range(len(the_sheet.col(1))):
    if i > 2:
        for j in range(1,4):
            box.append(str(the_sheet.col(j)[i]).split(":")[1])
        bigbox.append(box)
        box = []

print bigbox
```

And then I convert the nested list into a nested dictionary of nested set
i.e. `{'name':{'travel': set of travel, 'expense': set of expense}, ...}`

```
dbox = dict()

for name, travel, expense in bigbox:
    if name not in dbox:
        dbox[name] = {'travel': {travel}, 'expense': {expense}}
    else:
        dbox[name]['travel'].add(travel)
        dbox[name]['expense'].add(expense)

print dbox
```

lastly you print it out using some voodoo magic read the doc for more info

```
for name in dbox:
    print(name, 'to', "; ".join(dbox[name]['travel']), 'for', "; ".join(dbox[name]['expense']))
```

Hope this help I want to complain on how you don't give me the excel file I need to create that on my own next time include it and this is familar to some programming courses assignment??

Comment: thank you. could you please check "         box.append(str(the_sheet.col(j)[i]).split(":")[1])"? it's doesn't seem like work out.

Comment: use this instead `box.append(the_sheet.col(j)[i].value)` for that line no need to split I never use this library before sorry.

Comment: try changing `for j in range(3)` because it work for me having your excel file will be very helpful need to check whether out of index in i or j or you can just do the follow add a try and except block like `try: box.append(...) except: print(some error)`

Comment: thank you again. just unfortunately my knowledge isn't able to catch up.... hope you don't mind I choose another in place answer...

Answer (score 1):

Solution that comes to me at this moment :

```
from collections import defaultdict

the_file = xlrd.open_workbook("4_test.xlsx")
the_sheet = the_file.sheet_by_name("Sheet1")

nested_dict = lambda: defaultdict(nested_dict)
_dict = nested_dict()

for row_index in range(1, the_sheet.nrows):
    expense = []
    travel = []
    name = str(the_sheet.cell(row_index, 0).value)
    for row_index_1 in range(1, the_sheet.nrows):
        if name == str(the_sheet.cell(row_index_1, 0).value):
            travel.append(str(the_sheet.cell(row_index_1, 1).value))
            expense.append(str(the_sheet.cell(row_index_1, 2).value))
            _dict[name]['travel'] = travel
            _dict[name]['expense']= expense

for name in _dict:
    print name + " to "+ ",".join(set(_dict[name]['travel'])) + " for " + ",".join(set(_dict[name]['expense']))
```

Output ::

> Pintu to Europe for Bonous
>
> Jack to Europe,America for Hotel,Meal
>
> Mike  to America for Bonous,Hotel,Transport

Comment: thank you for the help. it's a good one (but seems takes very slow running on long list of spreadsheet data)